# How to setup shiny-server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which uses a RODBC connection?

Tags: r, odbc, ubuntu-14.04, vertica, shiny-server

I have been trying to setup a shiny-server on Ubuntu, following the steps given on shiny-server documentation and it works fine. Until, I use a RODBC connection to access a DB on Vertica Engine.

This is the first time I have set up a server and I cannot find any reference where I can use my shiny-server to create an open RODBC channel for my shiny app to create a connection with the DB.

I am able to access the DB using Vertica Client Drivers [on the official website] on a local machine, but when I try to do that through a shiny-server, the app blows up and R quits giving a message: An irrecoverable error has occurred.

I have tried for hours now but all my efforts are in vain, any leads or reference which drivers are to be installed to setup an ODBC connection through a server?

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with Shiny. I suggest you make R work with RODBC to connect to the DB and make some simple query work first.

Comment: Your question is also not helpful to help. There can be a lot of reasons why things are not working and they are hard to debug remotely without more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

@Gopala: I was seeking general reference manual as I didn't know the specifics. Anyway, I solved the problem using a JDBC connection instead of RODBC. My server works fine now.